# Metadata file does not match checksum after yum install

Tags: linux, centos, yum, elasticsearch

I'm trying to install elasticsearch using YUM repo on centos.
I configured the yum repo as described here :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/setup-repositories.html

but after the configuration I get :

```
https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/yum/repodata/primary.xml.gz: [Errno -1] Metadata file does not match checksum
```

I tried :

```
yum clean all
yum clean metadata
rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*
```

but the problem persists

this command work too and I get an XML

```
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/yum/repodata/primary.xml.gz
```

tried the same on centos machine in a different network and it worked the first try, this is the reason I guess it somehow related to network \ certificates.

any directions will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing solved the proxy problem I had is :

https://sites.google.com/site/kbinstuff/yum-and-proxies